# Getting StackOverflowError in Depth First Search

Tags: java, stack, stack-overflow, depth-first-search

This program attempts to solve a Maze by using a Stack class I created and Depth First Search algorithm.I am getting the error when `location = stack.peek();` and `findPath( maze,location,stack );`. I am guessing i have to change the recursive call to fix the error. I am not sure how to implement this though.

**My LinkedStack Class**

```
import java.awt.Point;
public class LinkedStack {
private Node top;

public LinkedStack() {
    top = null;
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return top == null;
}
public void push( Point p ) {
    top = new Node (p, top);
}
public Point pop() {
    Point retVal = new Point(0,0);
    if( isEmpty() ){
        System.out.println("Nothing to remove");
    }else{
        retVal = top.getValue();
        top = top.getNext();
    }
    return retVal;
}
public Point peek() {
    Point retVal = new Point(0,0);
    if( isEmpty() ){
        System.out.println("Stack is Empty");
    }else{
        retVal = top.getValue();
    }
    return retVal;
}
public String toString(){
    String s = "";
    Node n = top;
    while( n != null ){
        s = s + n.getValue() + " ";
        n = n.getNext();
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

**Main Class Where StackOverFlowError is Occurring**

```
//Should mark location of path taken with '.'
//Should check neighboring spots of location (up,right,down,left)
//Should check if valid locations
public static boolean findPath( char [][] maze, Point location, LinkedStack stack ){
    boolean hasSolution = false;
    stack.push(location);

    do{
        maze[location.x][location.y] = '.';

        if( location.y > 0 ){
            if( maze[location.x][location.y - 1] == ' '){
                stack.push(new Point( location.x, location.y - 1));
                maze[location.x][location.y - 1] = '.';
            }
        }
        if( location.y < maze[location.x].length ){
            if( maze[location.x][location.y + 1] == ' '){
                stack.push(new Point( location.x, location.y + 1));
                maze[location.x][location.y + 1] = '.';
            }
        }
        if( location.x < maze.length ){
            if( maze[location.x + 1][location.y] == ' '){
                stack.push(new Point( location.x + 1, location.y ));
                maze[location.x + 1][location.y] = '.';
            }
        }
        if( location.x > 0 ){
            if( maze[location.x - 1][location.y] == ' '){
                stack.push(new Point( location.x - 1, location.y ));
                maze[location.x - 1][location.y] = '.';
            }
        }
        if( maze[location.x][location.y] == 'f' ){
             hasSolution = true;
        }

        location = stack.peek();
        stack.pop();
        findPath( maze,location,stack );
    }while( !location.equals('f') && !stack.isEmpty() );
    return hasSolution;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to the conditional in the do/while: `!location.equals('f')` - isn't location an instance of java.awt.Point?

Comment: Compilers don't know what will happen at runtime.

Comment: @copeg Not sure if I understand your question. '!location.equals('f')' is the value of the Point in the array. 'f' is the finish location in the maze.

Comment: Yes, but `location.equals('f')` will be false in virtually every case (equality of a Point to a Character). Do you mean `max[location.x][location.y] == 'f'`?

Comment: @copeg Thanks for your correction, this is what i meant, but I am still getting StackOverFlowError.

Comment: @xerx593 Is `pop()` not removing the top of the stack? That is what it is intended to do.

Comment: I take a closer look! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please change the following lines:

```
       ...
       location = stack.peek();
       stack.pop();
       findPath( maze,location,stack );
    } while( !location.equals('f') && !stack.isEmpty() );
    ...
```

to:

```
        ...
        location = stack.peek();
        stack.pop();
        //findPath(maze, location, stack);
    } while (!(hasSolution || stack.isEmpty()));
    ...
```

The inner `findPath()` recurses infinitely! (1.) And as the comments correctly state, you try to compare a Point(x,y) with a `f`(character), the while-loop could never terminate. (2.)

**EDIT**: This will still not fix your issue, because: `hasSolution` will never be `true` (has not the slightest chance!) - why? - Because you (always) set `maze[x][y] = '.';` (never set `'f'`), and try to set `hasSolution = maze[x][y] == 'f'` (this will *always* yield `false`)

Please re-consider your algorithm&approach! What should maze contain? and when it should change?